# ModSecurity - Is there a way to configure DetectionOnly per Rule

Tags: mod-security

Using Mod-Security I would like to have my production system blocking requests (SecRuleEngine On), but for some of the rules (perhaps provided with an update of the RuleSet) I would like to get notified. This should help me to identify False-Postive before bringing the Rule really in production.

In other words, I would like to configure DetectionOnly for a list of Rules, while others are still blocked.

Is there a way to configured that with ModSecurity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update a specific rule, like this:

```
SecRuleUpdateActionById 12345 "pass,log"
```

Alternatively you can write your own rules to turn off the rule engine for certain scenario. See this questions for example: [Set mod_security to detectionOnly for a specific page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38620441/set-mod-security-to-detectiononly-for-a-specific-page)